# How to convert a 2 1d arrays to one 1d arrays but both values should be inside one element

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

i really dont how to phrase this properly so I apologise in advance. 
So lets say i have 2, 1D arrays

```
array1 = [2000, 2100, 2800]
array2 =[20, 80, 40]
```

Now how do i convert them into an 2d array in python like shown below

```
2dArray = [[2000, 20], [2100, 80], [2800, 40]]
```

So 2 id arrays to look like the one above in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple NumPy solution - `np.array([...]).T`:

```
In [6]: np.array([a1, a2]).T
Out[6]:
array([[2000,   20],
       [2100,   80],
       [2800,   40]])
```

Another NumPy solution, which uses [vstack()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) method:

```
In [142]: np.vstack((array1, array2)).T
Out[142]:
array([[2000,   20],
       [2100,   80],
       [2800,   40]])
```

or using [np.column_stack()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
In [144]: np.column_stack([array1, array2])
Out[144]:
array([[2000,   20],
       [2100,   80],
       [2800,   40]])
```

Another "slow" solution would be to use built-in [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function?

```
In [131]: np.array(list(zip(array1, array2)))
Out[131]:
array([[2000,   20],
       [2100,   80],
       [2800,   40]])
```

Explanation:

```
In [132]: list(zip(array1, array2))
Out[132]: [(2000, 20), (2100, 80), (2800, 40)]
```

**Timing** for two 1M elements arrays:

```
In [145]: a1 = np.random.randint(0, 10**6, 10**6)

In [146]: a2 = np.random.randint(0, 10**6, 10**6)

In [147]: a1.shape
Out[147]: (1000000,)

In [148]: a2.shape
Out[148]: (1000000,)

In [149]: %timeit np.array(list(zip(a1, a2)))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.78 s per loop

In [150]: %timeit np.vstack((a1, a2)).T
100 loops, best of 3: 6.4 ms per loop

In [151]: %timeit np.column_stack([a1, a2])
100 loops, best of 3: 7.62 ms per loop

In [14]: %timeit np.array([a1, a2]).T
100 loops, best of 3: 6.36 ms per loop     # <--- WINNER!
```

Comment: yes thank you so much, please can explain it a little bit thank you

Comment: Thank you soo much! God Bless

Comment: @MaxU interestingly - I get the opposite... `%timeit np.vstack((a1, a2)).T` -> `100000 loops, best of 3: 14.4 µs per loop` and `%timeit np.column_stack([a1, a2])` -> `100000 loops, best of 3: 11.4 µs per loop`...

Comment: @JonClements, what are the shapes of your arrays?

Comment: Ooops - I didn't run it on the right arrays... I'll try that and see if I get the same thing else err... we'll pretend I didn't say anything? :p

Comment: @JonClements, i had a little shock when i saw your `14.4 µs` versus my `6.4 ms` and started to think that i definitely have to upgrade my notebook ;-)

Comment: @MaxU nope - you're right - although I seem to get a larger difference: 2.46ms vs 5.79ms

Comment: @JonClements, thank you for your timings - i think i'll have to upgrade my notebook...

Comment: `np.array([a1, a2]).T` is even faster for me, and `np.stack([a1, a2], axis=-1)` is slower than all the numpy solutions

Comment: There's no point using `np.asarray` here, since that is for when you think you might already be working with an array - here, you're certain you've got a list. Also, you might want to move your winner arrow!