# Syntax for np.where on multi element 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 separate arrays of the following structure which I have simplified for the purpose of this question, the arrays I am working with are on the scale of 10,000 elements plus:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])
```

Using the information covered here:
[How to convert a 2 1d arrays to one 1d arrays but both values should be inside one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563628/how-to-convert-a-2-1d-arrays-to-one-1d-arrays-but-both-values-should-be-inside-o)

I have created a 1D array where referencing 1 value returns 2 values:

```
 c = np.array([a,b]).T
 print(c)
[[1 4]
 [2 5]
 [3 6]]
```

What I wish to achieve is conducting an np.where or similar statement which returns an index number of this multi element array by either looking for the smallest pair value or conducting a search for 2 pairs of values. The statement will return the index value where both pairs of numbers are the lowest or whichever index matches . So something along the lines of this and subsequently the output also:

The input is the array c made by using `np.array().T` :

```
[[1 4]
 [2 5]
 [3 6]]
```

The desired output is a command along the lines of the following which returns an index value based on the smallest pair of values which in the array c would be:

```
[1 4]
```

Example output:

```
 np.where(min(c)) #Or Equivalent statement for locating position of an element
 >>> 0 #Index number
```

or:

```
np.where(c[] == 1,4) #Alternative condition to search for values
>>> 0
```

I have tried this but a value error is returned:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Ideally I would like the most efficient method possible as I am working with very large arrays.

Comment: How do you define smallest for a pair?

Comment: Essentially where if both elements of the single index are the smallest value e.g in the array c I would say that the first index of [1 4] would be the smallest value with both values being evaluated.

Comment: Think you need to clearly define the inputs, as it seems you have various ones scattered all over the question.

Comment: The input is the array c made using `np.array().T`, my bad for not clarifying as such properly.

Comment: So, something like : `c[np.lexsort(c.T)[0]]`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with lexsort, can you give me an example please?

Comment: Related post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825281/numpy-lexicographic-ordering

Comment: By the way, try `np.column_stack((a, b))`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck For building the array using np.array().T is faster as seen in the link in the main post so that's why I chose it.

Comment: @Divakar Lexographic and indirect sorting is something I'm not familiar with, in terms of my example what does the lexographic sorting/lexsort actually do?

Comment: @cd123: `np.column_stack()` is just as fast as what you're doing.  Try it.  It's within experimental error.  And clarity counts.